# Python: Importing files and creating a list for each file

Tags: python, for-loop, import

I am looping over a list containing 9 file names and trying to create 9 variables (i.e. one for each file that I open).

The code seems to import correctly but I cant get it to create 9 variables, I've only managed to create one.

Code that works and creates one list (the 9th file):

```
for i in category_list:
    j = category_list.index(i)
    with open(str(path) + category_list[j] + f_ext, 'rb') as f:
        d = pickle.load(f)
```

Code that gives me error "name 'd_' is not defined

```
for i in category_list:
    j = category_list.index(i)
    with open(str(path) + category_list[j] + f_ext, 'rb') as f:
        d_[i] = pickle.load(f)
```

I think I may need to either declare the variable (which doesn't feel right for python) or I'm missing something even more simple.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: hm... it seams Your forgot 4 spaces in second row ))

Comment: Python doesn't have declarations, but you still need to define stuff, and I can't see a definition for `d_`; I assume it's supposed to be a list. And as Vasyl Kolomiets said, your indentation is broken.

Comment: The indentation got deleted when I pasted from Spyder, have corrected the above

Comment: BTW, you can iterate over any iterable and get an index number at the same time: `for idx, item in enumerate(my_sequence):`

Comment: So do I have to define 9 empty lists before I load the 9 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm...  it seams it may works:

```
d_ = []
for category in category_list:
    with open(str(path) + category + f_ext, 'rb') as f:
        d_.append( pickle.load(f))
```

Isn't it?
If - it is so - try eat more Python-like code )

Comment: That works I guess, it creates one list with 9 elements, I can work with that!

Comment: You can write "d_ += pickle.load(f) ,"      but they say "d_.append(pickle.load(f))" is a bit "profy"